# Cannot click within dynamically inserted content

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a form that is dynamically inserted into the Google Map. However I cannot click any of the inputs.  I believe I need to add a listener somewhere but I'm not sure.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duEEt/1/)

```
    function googlemap() {

    // google map coordinates
    var posY = 37.765700,
        posX = -122.449134,
        location = new google.maps.LatLng(posY,posX),

        // offset location
        posY = posY + 0.055;
        offsetlocation = new google.maps.LatLng(posY,posX);

    var mapOptions = {
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        draggable: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 12,
        center: offsetlocation,
        // ROADMAP; SATELLITE; HYBRID; TERRAIN;
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    overlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    // create overlay marker
    overlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

        blip = document.createElement('div'),
        pulse = document.createElement('div');
        blip.className = 'blip';
        pulse.className = 'pulse';

        // createa dialog and grab contents from #mapcontents
        boxText = document.createElement("div");
        boxText.className = "dialog";
        mapContents = $('#mapcontents').html();
        boxText.innerHTML = mapContents;
        $('#mapcontents').remove();
        blip.appendChild(boxText);

        // append 'blip' marker
        this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(blip).appendChild(pulse);
    }

    // update blip positioning when zoomed
    overlay.prototype.draw = function(){

        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection(),
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(location, location),
            sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getSouthWest()),
            ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getNorthEast());

        blip.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
        blip.style.top = ne.y + 'px';



        // shift nav into view by resizing header
        var w = $('.dialog').width(),
            w = (w / 2) + 25,
            w = '-' + w + 'px';

            h = $('.dialog').height(),
            h = (h) + 100,
            h = '-' + h + 'px';

        $('.dialog').css({
            'margin-top' : h,
            'margin-left' : w
        });


    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0], mapOptions);

    // explicitly call setMap on this overlay
    function overlay(map) {
        this.setMap(map);
    }

    // center map when window resizes
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() { map.setCenter(location) });

    // center map when zoomed
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { map.setCenter(location) });

    // I have nfi what I'm doing but I think this click listener is part of the solution.
    google.maps.event.addListener('.dialog', 'click', function() {

        alert('ok');
    });

    // process contact form
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'domready', function() {

        $('button').click(function(e) {
            (e).preventDefault();

            alert('ok');

            return false;

            var name    = $(".contactform input[name='name']"),
                email   = $(".contactform input[name='email']"),
                message = $(".contactform textarea[name='message']"),
                error = false;

            // clear validation errors
            $('#contact input, #contact textarea').removeClass('error');

            if(name.val().length < 1)
                name.addClass("error");

            if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$/.test(email.val()))
                email.addClass("error");

            if(message.val().length < 1)
                message.addClass("error");

            // if error class exists
            if($(".error").length) return false;

            $(this).attr('disabled', true).prepend('<i class="load animate-spin"></i>');

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "lib/sendmail.php",
                data: $("#contactform").serialize()
            })
            .always(function(data) {

                $('h5').animate({opacity:0},function(){
                        $('h5').text("Email Sent!!")
                    .animate({opacity:1});
                });

                $('.contactform').animate({opacity:0},function(){
                        $('.contactform').html("<p class='success'>Thank You for your form submission. We will respond as soon as possible.</p>")
                    .animate({opacity:1});
                })

            });

        });

        return false;
    });


    // add overlay
    overlay = new overlay(map);
}
```

Any idea why I can't click the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to block propagation of `mousedown` map event to make inputs clickable:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(blip, 'mousedown', function (e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if(e.stopPropogation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

And you can do the same for `dbclick` to prevent map zooming: http://jsfiddle.net/gfKWz/1/

Answer (score 1):

The click-events fire fine for all these inputs, the issue here at first is that your code will never execute, because there is no `domready`-event for a `google.maps.Map`

Change this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'domready', function () {
```

into this:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
```

for observation of the events you may use `$.on()`, e.g.:

```
$(map.getDiv()).on('click','button',function (e) {/*some code*/});
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jcfDu/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jcfDu/)

Answer (score 0):

Your event has to be added in the `onAdd` function.

Currently, the event handler is created before the element. So it doesn't catch the click on this particular element.

http://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/duEEt/4/

Or you could create a new function for your overlay's bindings, just for the sake of clean-code :

```
overlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    [...]

    this.bindings();
}

overlay.prototype.bindings = function(){
   $("button").on("click",function(){
     alert("Click");
     return false;
   }
}
```

For now I have no real solution to your inputs problem.
Maybe by reattaching `mousedown`events to them, and force them to `focus()`:

```
$("input,textarea").on("mousedown",function(){$(this).focus();});
```

Same thing with your checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can click the inputs?

Comment: I think GMaps is bypassing all your mouse events on your overlay.

I can't find any solution (for now) but to reattach every events to your inputs. As seen here : http://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/duEEt/10/

Answer (score 0):

You use `$('button').click` which is triggered before the button is present on the dom. `.click()` binds the handler to all the current elements on the dom.

Better use `$('button').on('click', function(){});` which binds the click event handler to all the current *and future* instances of button on your page. This is especially handy if you dynamically add content on the page. Through ajax or otherwise.

Read more about jQuery .on() in here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The problem is GoogleMaps. It's not allowing the trigger to fire.

Answer (score 0):

On another note, since you use jQuery, why not use it all the way?

Like you can do:

```
$('#mapcontents')
    .clone()
    .wrap('<div class="dialog" />')
    .wrap('<div class="blip />')
    .appendTo( *selector* );
```

In order to quickly build some html and append it to the selected element. Much more readable (thus easier to maintain) than the DOM code you got there. Since you already use jQuery anyway.